# FastAPI, SQLAlchemy Session context

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am working on a project with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy 2.0. According to FastAPI docs, you should pass the Session (from sessionmaker) as Dependency. Something like this:

```py
# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

It just yields the Session and handles closing (commit, returning to pool). Would this also handle a rollback, if the exception is raised?

With SQLAlchemy alone, I would use a context manager, which handles that. But with FastAPI I am not sure. From SA docs:

```py
with Session() as session:
    with session.begin():
        [...]
```

And just a note at the end: I am not a fan of using a session per request in the middleware. I use the Session as Dependency now, but I have already encountered some issues: If I use a Session in the dependency, which is used as global (in APIRouter() ) it would use that Session even for the routes, that has their own Session dependency.

The issue is, that the Session on APIRouter() is used for something else, then the Session given as a dependency to the endpoint. But as only one Session is used, it mixed up objects in SQLAlchemy identity map and loading strategy.
That is just a note not related to the question directly.

Thank you.